# sending email notification in react and database saved in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, firebase, nodemailer

A simple way, I must email the user that they near deadlines, Deadline is a daytime ( mm/dd/yyyy mm: hh) and daytime save in firebase, the user has an account is mail address( xxx@gmail.com) and I have to send email to us when it's close to 1 hour.
A mail has a template :

```
 Hey { user-name} !
 you are about to expire on { the name of homework}, hurry up!
```

[i have a database  here]

```
stactoverflow-19119

    Deadline: 

             "14/02/2018 15:00"
    User: 

            "KienTT1234"
```

Can I implement that, Step by step, What can I do to retrieve datime on the database to compare, and how to send email to a user?

Answer (score 1):

You can create task with node that will send the email on the given date,
check : https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule 

Example :

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2018, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
   your_function_to_send_email();
});
```

Comment: so, you using schedule to handle this, thank you for your guide, Next, I want to understand how to send an email . Can you help me?

Comment: well you make a request to your database to get the wanted date/s and in the callback of the request you create your scheduled job !